# Node.js - what are the consequences of an async function not calling back?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**What area the consequences of an async function simply returning without calling back?**

I know you shouldn't do this. My question is hypothetical - I'm just interested to know what the consequences of doing this might be.

Is it bad for the stack?  Could it lead to memory leaks?

For example:

```
function whatAreMyConsequences(value, callback) {
     value++;
     if(value > 1000) {
         return;
     }

     callback(null, value);
}
```

Comment: Nothing? Not calling the callback is a path not taken. It's not like node js examines your function arguments and requires every possible callback there in to be called, otherwise, you couldn't have a different 'success' or 'error' callback as is often the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the calling code knows that the callback might not get called (and doesn't depend upon it for something in the logic flow), then there are no consequences.  There is no more or less chance of a memory leak if the callback is not called.  It has no net impact on the stack whether it is called or not.

A function passed as an argument is just an argument to the receiving function.  The receiving function can decide to do whatever it wants with that function.  It can call it always, never or sometimes.

Of course, the caller will be expecting some sort of behavior so it is up to the receiving function to hold up its end of the contract or the caller's code will not work correctly, but that's just correct programming logic.

In fact, it would be perfectly valid programming to have a function that accepts four callbacks and it decides which of the four to call based on something that happens or some other arguments that are called.

Look at promises:

```
 $.ajax(...).then(mySuccessHandler, myErrorHandler);
```

Only one of those two callbacks will be called and this is by design.

Comment: Heh, that was quick.  Thank you.